# Some problem with installing springsource-tool-suite in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

[image: The problem occurred when installing sts]

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: Spring IDE Boot Microservices Dash 3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.feature.feature.group 3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE)
 Missing requirement: Boot 3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot 3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.apache.commons.collections 0.0.0' but it could not be found
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Spring Boot Dashboard View 3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash 3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE)
  To: osgi.bundle; org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot 0.0.0
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Spring IDE Boot Microservices Dash 3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.feature.feature.group 3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE)
  To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash [3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE,3.9.10.201909171046-RELEASE]
```

Eclipse version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)

The zip installed: `springsource-tool-suite-3.9.10.RELEASE-e4.12.0-updatesite.zip`

I can't even figure out why this problem occurred...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Details* the message says that the **Apache Common plug-in/bundle** (`org.apache.commons.collections`) of any version (`0.0.0`) **is missing** (it is not installed and it is not contained in the ZIP). It is directly **required by** *Boot* and indirectly required (because *Boot* is required or something is required that requires the *Boot* plug-in/bundle) by the ***Spring Boot Dashboard View*** and by the ***Spring IDE Boot Microservices Dash***.

Download the [**`org.apache.commons.collections_3.2.2.v201511171945.jar`**](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20190726180751/repository/plugins/org.apache.commons.collections_3.2.2.v201511171945.jar) file and put it **into the `dropins`** folder in your Eclipse installation directory. Restart Eclipse and install STS3 from the ZIP as you did before.

Alternatively, if you have an internet connection, in the *Install* dialog check the checkbox *Contact all update sites during install to find required software* and make sure all required stuff is contained in the configured update sites (*Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites*).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try the method you said.

Comment: If you go with the update-sites approach it may help to add the Eclipse orbit update site to 'Available Update Sites' in the preferences. You can find the repository url to use on this webpage: https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20190827152740/)